# How to insert data to database in another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using Sql Server 2005.
There are two different Sql Servers.
I need to get data from one server and insert them into database on other server.
As a example assume there is two servers call A and B.
A has DB call ADB and B has DB call BDB.
I need to get data from ADB and insert them into BDB.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it many ways..

If both servers are in the same network use **COPY DATABASE** option in SSMS

[COPY Databade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx)

IF both servers are not in the same network, then you could **generate  script** from one database and execute in another

a detailed example is [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-copy-database-with-data-generate-t-sql-for-inserting-data-from-one-table-to-another-table/)

Another option is to take **backup** of the database and restore it in the other server, which will be very simple and effective if the data is huge

Answer (score 0):

On Server A add a linked server (B)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Then you can transfer data between the two.

[Export table data from one SQL Server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009189/export-table-data-from-one-sql-server-to-another)

HTH