# How to insert data from multiple tables to multiple tables by using SSIS?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have almost 106+ tables in database and now I need to load data from these tables into another database.

Table structure of source and destination database are same. There is a status table in the database and all tables have a Primary Key ID field. All the tables have Primary key and Foreign key relationship.

Status table contain the ID field of tables and anther column contain a status of related ID field that this ID has completed its task.

I need to transfer data those ID number will match with Status table where ID status is 1 or something like this. I need to insert Identity column also, and because of all the table have PK and FK relationship so i have to insert data into tables with referential constraints.

So, my questions here is: To fulfill my above scenario how can I load data from multiple tables to multiple tables by using SSIS because it is not one time thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy data between two server instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002849/copy-data-between-two-server-instances)

Comment: Can't you just use Stored procedures?

Comment: Is backup/restore an option here?

Answer (score 0):

Status table idea is not clear.i hv 160+ tables then status table will contain what ? give example.

Of course you hv to start with diagram/flow

suppose

```
table1 id pk
table2 id pk (table1 id fk)
table3 id pk (table2 id fk)

insert into table1
insert into table2
insert into table3
```

In my example you can't first inert into table3 becasue of FK constraint.
This way first you hv to make flow.

Comment: Status table contain the ID field of tables and anther column contain a status of related ID field that this ID has completed its task. and table diagram you said, my case is also same.