# copy data from a table on server1 to another table on server2

Tags: sql-server-2014

how i can copy data from a table on server1 to another table on server2 using query?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009189/export-table-data-from-one-sql-server-to-another

Comment: @MahdiBagheri Using Jquery??

Comment: @JibinBalachandran No.Using Query on sql

Comment: This post shows zero research or effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [server2].[database].[schema].[table]
( col1, col2, col3...)
SELECT
( col1, col2, col3...)
FROM [server1].[database].[schema].[table]
```

server2 would need to be a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)