# How to export .sql file with data from SQL Server and import it in MySQL? Can I do that?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I have had working knowledge on MySQL for years. And I used to export the schema and it's data as .sql file from my MySql database and import it where it's required. It worked for me.

But Recently I happened to replicate the data from a database which is in SQLServer and import it in my MySql database.
For this, I'm not able to generate .sql file for data but for Scripts(Schema) from SQLServer. 
What is the process to make it happen? Since all SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle are all RDBMS Softwares which follows the standard. So what's the problem in it?

Comment: *Why* do that, when SQL Server already has SSIS and wizards to transfer data between multiple sources? Anyway, different databases have different features and different data types.

Comment: For example, MySQL needs dumps because it doesn't have real backup unless you buy (or compile) the enterprise edition. SQL Server has real backup in all versions and editions. SQL Server also has built-in real replication mechanisms - changes are replicated to subscribers according to schedules. Dumps are neither replication or backup mechanisms, just scripting.

Comment: Can one server see the other? If yes, you can setup MySQL as a linked server and copy data to it. Or, you can use SSIS to move data. It's the technology behind the `Export Data` wizard in SSMS. You can save the wizard's settings as a separate package that can be run on a schedule, or edited with SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: BTW no database vendor is fully standard compliant. MySQL is probably the worst offender, with several quirks, undocumented features and missing functionality. For example, unlike Oracle, DB2 or SQL Server, it doesn't have a Unicode text type, just encoded fields.

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to do so.

Solutions 1: You can use phpmyadmin, it has export and import feature. It can be used directly, it copies data also. I have done that multiple times on a college project, worked great for me.

Solution 2: You may refer here for more: [Export table data from one SQL Server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009189/export-table-data-from-one-sql-server-to-another)

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to copy data from one table to another

Comment: Question is for replication only. Refer para 2 of it.